# CustomMapType: SetZoom > 30

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I set maxZoom:50 for custom map type, but I can zoom only to 30 level. 
map.setZoom(50) zooming to 30 zoom level.
How can I zoom to level more than 30?

Idea: show mall on custom map. 3 zoom level per floor. Start zoom level is 18. If mall have 5 floors I need (18+(5*3)) = 33 zoom level.

Comment: set the initial zoom level to 12 or 15

Comment: In this way main map will be shown. I need only mall map. I have only one map on site for all(city, mall, stores, etc.).Main map maxZoom is set to 17.